# I want to check if a column has specific values in list of entity objects.?How can i do that?

Tags: java

I have a list of `Student` objects `studentList`. Each `student` that has a `name` and a `marks` attributes.

I want to check if the marks column contains values `>=60` and `<70`. Is there a way to check this other than looping the list for each student and check for value?

Comment: What about `Stream#filter`?

Comment: what is type of marks field? Array of integers?

Answer (score 2):

As @Amongalen suggested, you can use `Stream#filter`:

```java
List<Student> result = studentList.stream()
    .filter(student -> student.marks>=60 && student.marks <70)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can find a more detailed explanation in https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/

Answer (score 0):

#### Sample `Student` class:

```java
class Student{
    String name;
    int marks;

    public Student() {
        super();
    }

    public Student(String name, int marks) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", marks=" + marks + "]";
    }
}
```

#### Main method for `Test`:

```java
public class Test{
    public static void main(String []args){
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student("ABC",65));
        list.add(new Student("XYZ",85));
        list.add(new Student("CDE",55));
        list.add(new Student("FGH",75));
        List<Student> resultList = list.stream()
            .filter(o -> (o.marks>=65 && o.marks<75))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(resultList );
    }
}
```